# Difference between npmjs replicate and npmjs registry

Tags: npm, npm-registry

For research purpose, I am interested in getting a full list of npm package names. Some existing answer points to https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/_all_docs, but the url is `replicate.npmjs.com`, and it seems to be a different registry than `http://registry.npmjs.com/`. For example, as of now, http://registry.npmjs.com/ 's `doc_count` is 1844996, but https://replicate.npmjs.com/ has 1419077.

What is the difference between `registry.npmjs.com` and `replicate.npmjs.com`? Are they the same or different registries? What are they used for? Which one is the "default" one used by the npm CLI?

Answer (score 1):

`https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/` supports scoped packages with `%2f` in the url:

- https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/@sindresorhus/is (404)
- https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/@babel/core (404)
- https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/@sindresorhus%2fis (200)
- https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/@babel%2fcore (200)

Whereas as the `https://registry.npmjs.org/` works for both

- https://registry.npmjs.org/@sindresorhus/is (200)
- https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/core (200)
- https://registry.npmjs.org/@sindresorhus%2fis (200)
- https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fcore (200)

Also here's a *incomplete* doc about the `registry` endpoint: https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REPLICATE-API.md

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. `replicate.npmjs.com` does support scoped packages, but the `/` must be URL encoded as `%2f` e.g. https://replicate.npmjs.com/registry/@sindresorhus%2fis

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `replicate.npmjs.com` exposes the CouchDB [_changes API](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/api/database/changes.html) that can be used to replicate information about packages in the primary npmjs registry (`registry.npmjs.com`).

If you are interested in performing research on all npm packages I suggest you take a look at this tutorial by the npm team: https://github.com/npm/registry-follower-tutorial